# PostgreSQL: WAL files on server are not deleted

Tags: centos, postgresql

Previously, the server was configured to hot_standby master. After a while he began to work alone. I changed the settings according to it, but the amount of WAL files is still growing ...

How to get rid of it?

OS - CentOS

`postgresql.conf`:

```
listen_addresses = '192.168.1.24,localhost'     
max_connections = 100           
shared_buffers = 32MB           
wal_level = minimal         
archive_mode = off      
archive_command = 'test ! -f /var/lib/pgsql/docsrv/pgarch/%f && cp %p /var/lib/pgsql/docsrv/pgarch/%f'      
max_wal_senders = 1     
log_destination = 'syslog'
log_timezone = 'Europe/Samara'
update_process_title = off
datestyle = 'iso, mdy'
timezone = 'Europe/Samara'
lc_messages = 'C'           
lc_monetary = 'C'           
lc_numeric = 'C'            
lc_time = 'C'               
default_text_search_config = 'pg_catalog.english'
```

Comment: Is this a cosmetic issue or is this actually causing a problem? Removing or shrinking the WAL files will mean they'll have to be created/grown the next time they're needed, causing extra I/O and fragmentation.

Comment: It actually causing problem becouse of exhaustion of free space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you restart after changing the setting? Try

```
show wal_level;
```

and

```
show archive_mode;
```

at psql prompt

and try

```
show config_file;
```

to see which config file is used by the server

Comment: Also `SHOW wal_keep_segments`; that's likely to be the relevant setting here.

Comment: `wal_level - hot_standby`; `archive_mode - on`; But why? In postgresql.conf `wal_level = minimal`!

Comment: Even after restarting server...

Comment: So you change of settings did not take effect. What do you see in the log files?  If there are errors in the values you provided for settings, it should show up in the log files.

Comment: I don't see any errors about config in /var/log/messages

Comment: and in `pgstartup.log` too

Comment: Is it using the right config file? Try  postgres=# show config_file ;
                 config_file                  
----------------------------------------------
 /var/lib/postgresql/9.3/main/postgresql.conf
(1 row)

Comment: oh, you're right! it was another config file) thank you so much!

Comment: You are welcome :)